# Matlab: Gradient color spots according to percentage

Tags: matlab, colors, gradient, percentage, repeat

I want to paint some edges on my plot using gradient color according to their repetition percentage.
So the most repeated edge on my graph to be red, the next lesser to be orange and the edge with the less repetitions to be light beige.
The Percentage of the repetition can be obtained from a txt file.
The rest area of the plot i would like to stay intact in white color. Something like the next image (consider objects shape and size irrelevant, just the color gradient is what i am interested for).

[image: Gradient map]

How can i do this with matlab?

My approach so far:

**EDIT it works with the addition of the hold all cmd**

```
for jkl=1:size(edges,1) 
   plot(edges(jkl,1), edges(jk,2),'^','Color',[edgespercentage(jkl)/100 0 1], 'LineWidth', 2.5,'DisplayName', 'Edges with gradient color'); hold all
end
```

But as i see plot cant keep each iteration's color and plots at the end the last calculated color only (as expected).

Thank you in advance.

**Solution found with the tip of [David K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324595/david-k) (Thank you!)**
[image]

Comment: How are you plotting these edges? You may be able to use the `Color` property of your LineSeries.

Comment: I use meshgrid for plotting those edges. If edges are over 0 are looking like this ^ if under like this V. Just want to color its value with gradient color according to their repetition, something like this graph: http://tpucdn.com/reviews/EVGA/GTX_760_SC_ACX_Cooler/images/clock_vs_voltage.jpg

Comment: Do you have the plots held? Put `hold all;` on the line after the plot function.

Comment: Thank you! I tried with hold and hold on but didnt tried with hold all!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but give it a shot:

```
mesh(xvals,yvals,zvals,repititionVals);
colormap('hot');
```

You can play around with `colormap` to get the exact shading you want, but I think either `hot` or `autumn` is the closest predefined map to what you're looking for

Comment: Nop doesn't work the way i need. I will update the problem description in few minutes.